# Python Flask 0.10: fix exception being thrown

Tags: python, flask, uwsgi

Flask introduced the following change in 0.10:

- Flask will now raise an error if you attempt to register a new function on an already used endpoint.

I've used the following code on my home page:

```
# ...
# ...
# some endpoints registered there 

@theApp.route("/<path:filename>")
def static(filename):
    if (os.path.isfile("templates/" + filename)):
        return render_template(filename)
    elif (os.path.isfile("static/" + filename)):
        return theApp.send_static_file(filename)
    else:
        return (render_template("404.html"), 404)
```

This handler is used to handle everything that exists, no matter static or template.
Now this gives me an exception during startup.
How I can avoid an exception without registering too detailed handlers?

Comment: It doesn't give me an error. Paste the rest of your code please, seems like that's where the problem lies.

Comment: https://github.com/georgthegreat/leftparagraphs/blob/master/index.py3k - github page with entire file. Works well with Flask-0.9.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you dont pass `endpoint` to `route`, by default the endpoint is the decorated function name. Flask already has a `static` endpoint, used for serving files from your static dir. Renaming the function or passing `endpoint='mystatic'` to the `route` decorator should fix it.

[URL Route Registrations](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#url-route-registrations)

Comment: Thanks. This fixed an issue. But I've found very strange stuff. If I request `/static/style.css` Flask will responce with a `style.css` file content. Is it possible to uninstall default `static` endpoint?

Comment: @Georg - aren't you handling static files in the route you have defined in your question?  What makes you think that Flask's default handler is handling them?

Comment: I do not define any handler to `/static/path/to/file` — I define `/path/to/file` route in the handler above. But `/static/path/to/file is active`. (e. g. I can access both `/static/css/style.css` and `/css/style.css`)